# Using Moles to mock System.Net.Sockets

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moles

I'm trying to use Moles to mock the Socket class in System.Net.Sockets. I have successfully generated the .moles file and building it did add a System.Net.Moles assembly to my references but It dose not generate the MSocket class. In fact only the MIPEndPointCollection class is generated.

Here is a sample class that uses System.Net.Sockets.Socket:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace MyProject
{
    public static class Communicator
    {
        public static int Send(string messages)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messages);
            int bytesSent = 0;
            using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {
                socket.Connect("localhost", 1234);
                bytesSent = socket.Send(bytes);
            }

            return bytesSent;
        }
    }
}
```

A dumy test class:

```
using MyProject;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Net.Moles;
using Microsoft.Moles.Framework;

[assembly: MoledType(typeof(System.Net.Sockets.Socket))]

namespace MyProjectTest
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class CommunicatorTest
    {
        private TestContext testContextInstance;
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get { return testContextInstance; }
            set { testContextInstance = value; }
        }

        [TestMethod()]
        [HostType("Moles")]
        public void SendTest()
        {
            //dose not exist in the System.Net.Moles namespace:
            //MSocket.Send = deligate(){ return 0; };
            int bytesSent = Communicator.Send("Test Message");
            Assert.AreEqual(0, bytesSent);
        }
    }
}
```

And my .moles file:

```
<Moles xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/moles/2010/">
  <Assembly Name="System.Net" />
</Moles>
```

Can someone pleas point out what is wrong with this and what to do to make it work. I know that there are other ways to mock out the Socket class for example with a wrapper class that implements my own interface but I'm only interested in doing this using Moles.

--Thanks Daniel

Comment: "I know that there are other ways to mock out the Socket class for example with a wrapper class that implements my own interface but I'm only interested in doing this using Moles." - IMHO the **only** valid reason for that is if you're dealing with a relatively large legacy codebase. If that's not the case, go with the wrapper + interface.

Comment: @TrueWill That seems consistent with a blog post of yours I saw recently.  I like your concept of the thin, stripped-down wrapper for externalities to keep your code as decoupled as possible.  I've experimented with that even with something as simple as the XDocument API and generally find it to be a solid approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, Moling the System assembly is quirky.  Try this for the second line of your .moles file:

```
<Assembly Name="System" ReflectionOnly="true" />
```